# What does the above simplify into when $f_1$ and $f_2$ are indicator functions of convex subsets $C$ and $D$ of $X$, respectively?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the expression

$$\partial (f_1\Box f_2)(\bar{x})=\partial f_1(\bar{x_1})\cap\partial f_2(\bar{x_2}).$$

What does the above simplify into when $f_1$ and $f_2$ are indicator functions of convex subsets $C$ and $D$ of $X$, respectively?

Considering that the sub differential of the indicator function is the normal cone I have the following proof. Please confirm for me that I am on the right path with this proof.

proof
\begin{align*}
\partial(\iota_{C}\Box\iota_{D})(\bar{x})&=\partial\iota_{C}(\bar{x_1})\cap\iota_{D}(\bar{x_2})\\
&=N_{C}(\bar{x_1})\cap N_{D}(\bar{x_1})\\
&=N_{C+D}(\bar{x_1}+\bar{x_2})\\
&=\partial(\iota_{C+D}(\bar{x_1}+\bar{x_2}))
\end{align*}
Thus, when the functions are the indicator functions we see that the corollary simplifies down to
$$\partial(f_1\Box f_2)=\partial(\iota_{C+D}(\bar{x_1}+\bar{x_2}))$$ $\Box$

Comment: What is the square operation?

Comment: *Infimal convolution*, I guess.

Comment: What is $\bar{x}_1$ ? And $\bar{x}_2$ ? What's their relation to $\bar{x}$ ?

Comment: "Consider the expression ..." is that supposed to be a theorem ? Can you provide a reference ?

Comment: See Cor 2.65 in "An Easy Path to Convex Analysis and Applications" by Boris S. Mordukhovich and Nguyen Mau Nam